# Display the last date, regardless of articles

Tags: date-time, date

i would like to display a date on my Blog. I have used this Code for displaying the date:

`<?php the_time('l, j. F Y'); ?>`

But that uses the time of the latest article. How can i display the current date?

Comment: not a wordpress problem - see php function `date()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: If this is a crosspost with the same question on serverfault, reference any help from there. And if this isn't for WordPress, is belongs on serverfault or stackoverfow.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the PHP `date()` function as Michael suggested. So your date code might look like this:

```
<?php echo date('l, j. F Y'); ?>
```

Comment: Yes but that Doesn't work properly. I need an german date. So i gotta have to use the setlocale () and strftime () functions. And that works not for me. See my question on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/345024/php-setlocale-german-date-time-doesnt-work